# Creating a user list with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise

I have Devise set up with Omniauth-facebook, which pulls in the user's city, among other things. I have pages for the different cities, and on this page want to have a list of the users from this city. At this point, I am just trying to get any user list to work. I am having a hard time finding any good documentation on how to do this.

I created a new users_controller, with the following

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
@users = User.all
end
end
```

And on the page that I want to list them on, I have

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<div class="span12"><%= user.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

When I access the page, I am getting the error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

1: <div class="newyorkbg">
2: <h1>New York</h1>
3: </div>
4: 
5: <% @users.each do |user| %>
6:    <div class="span12"><%= user.name %></div>
7: <% end %>
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you do User.all in rails console? And also, what is the file name of your view?

Comment: in the console, I am getting the message -bash: User.all: command not found - and the file name of the view i this case is newyork.html.erb

Comment: did you do it in the console you get after executing `rails console`?

Comment: ah sorry, I did not execute rails console first. It now loads the users and their corresponding information

Comment: User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => [#<User id: 13, email: "...", encrypted_password: "...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 10, current_sign_in_at: "2013-06-24 01:50:53", last_sign_in_at: "2013-06-24 01:50:33", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-06-20 02:13:31", updated_at: "2013-06-24 01:50:53", name: "Jeremy", city: "Brooklyn, New York", provider: "facebook", uid: "838612", image: "http://graph.facebook.com/838612/picture?type=squar...">]

Comment: okay. What is the name of your view file? the instance variables you initialize in index action will be available only for index view

Comment: it is newyork.html.erb

Comment: rename it to index.html.erb or index.html.haml depending on the template engine you are using

Comment: I would rather not do that, as I want a separate page for each city with a user list. Is it possible to initialize the instance variable so that it's available on the newyork.html.erb page?

Comment: You can explicitly render the template in your controller. add `render :template => "users/newyork"` to the end of your index action

Comment: The problem seems to be that @Users is triggering a "nil" value. I can't figure out why...

Comment: That cannot be nil if you are using it in the right view. It can only be an empty array